# xna 3d water object and water drops

Tags: object, 3d, xna, splash-screen

I'm making a 3d game in xna.
I want to make a cube of water (part of a mob) that will splash a little,
but I cant think of a way to render this kind of cube or a shader with this effect,
any suggestions?
*BTW sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/31417/180167.aspx#180167

Hope it helps you!